# Increased ec2 volume is not listed on the instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I wanted to increase the size of the root partition of my ec2 instance, from 50 to 80Go

I increased the size of the volume using:

`aws ec2 modify-volume --volume-id vol-xxxxxxx --size 80`

According to aws, the volume was correctly resized: from the console or with the cli, I correctly see that the size is 80Go:

[image]

But then, when I ssh into the ec2 instance, the size of the disk is still 50Go:

```
# lsblk -e7
NAME            MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
nvme0n1         259:0    0   50G  0 disk 
└─nvme0n1p1     259:1    0   50G  0 part /
```

Thus, I cannot resize the partition.

I should see something like `nvme0n1         259:0    0   80G  0 disk`

Why the instance is not seeing the correct size of the disk? And how can I fix this?

Also, this is a prod instance and I **cannot** restart it. It should work without downtime.

Thanks

**EDIT**

Here is the output of `fdisk -l`: (I removed all the `/dev/loopX`)

```
# fdisk -l
Disk /dev/nvme0n1: 50 GiB, 53687091200 bytes, 104857600 sectors
Disk model: Amazon Elastic Block Store              
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x093eb684

Device         Boot Start       End   Sectors Size Id Type
/dev/nvme0n1p1 *     2048 104857566 104855519  50G 83 Linux
```

Answer (score 2):

[Extend a Linux file system after resizing a volume](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/recognize-expanded-volume-linux.html)

> For volumes that have a partition, such as the root volume shown in the previous step, use the growpart command to extend the partition. Notice that there is a space between the device name and the partition number.

```sh
sudo growpart /dev/nvme0n1 1
```

> To extend the file system on each volume, use the resize2fs command.

```sh
sudo resize2fs /dev/nvme0n1p1
```

Comment: My problem here is that the size of the disk is not the same as the size aws is showing me in the console. The disk size should be 80Go whereas `lsblk` shows me only 50Go. I'm talking about disk size, not partition

Comment: @iAmoric I am not sure if you followed above commands while increasing the volume.  Because those were not included in the OP. So just want to confirm you followed the above procedure for increasing the volume size?

Comment: I'm going to do this right after I've managed to increase the disk size. You commands are to increase the partition size. I cannot do that if the disk size itself is not increased first -> https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/requesting-ebs-volume-modifications.html

Comment: @iAmoric can you run `fdisk -l` and `dmesg -T` and share the output? and try to see the `lsblk` listing without `exclusion` i.e. `-e` option. And double check if the correct volume was resized.

Comment: See my edited question for the output of `fdisk`. For `dmesg` the output is really to big to be posted here. Is there something in particular to check ? Or at least to filter ? For `lsblk` the `-e` option just allow me to avoid all the `/dev/loopX` devices

Comment: @iAmoric the last resort is to `reboot` the instance and see if that shows the correct size. Because this sometimes happens. Plus `dmesg -T` command output you can check for any errors if occurred for increasing the size.

Comment: Actually, `dmesg -T` doesn't say anything from several days (last output from 29/01). I increased the volume size yesterday

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228206/discussion-between-samtoddler-and-iamoric).